Azure SQL returning different output for query with variable and query with hardcoded values
SQL Server is returning different results for the following two queries that I expect to return the same output:
Query 1:
DECLARE @year INT = 2024
DECLARE @month INT = 7
SELECT *
FROM udf_a(@year, @month)

Output:

Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Divide by zero error encountered.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
Total execution time: 00:00:06.520

Query 2:
SELECT *
FROM udf_a(2024, 7)

Output:

The resultset containing my expected data

udf_a is a table-valued user-defined function that calls udf_b another table-valued user-defined function within its body. udf_b has the same parameters as udf_a. I.e. the value of @year and @month is forwarded to udf_b. But I believe this is irrelevant as I am passing the same parameter in the queries above and expect the same output.
The MSSQL version is: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Jun  3 2024 16:19:04    Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
I am running this in Azure Data Studio v1.48.1
Function skeleton:
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_a](@year INT, @month INT)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
    SELECT *
    FROM BLAH
    WHERE BLAH = BLAH
GO


It's probably inlining bug as usual, try to disable inlining in the function definition

Thank you for the comment @siggemannen. Could you please elaborate on this a little? I am not sure what you mean by 'inlining'. Here is how I've written both my functions: CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_a](@year INT, @month INT). I've added the skeleton in my question.

You can read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver16

Thank you, I saw this talks about scalar user-defined functions, not sure if it is applicable in my scenario as both my functions are table-valued.

Well, did you try the hint? actually, now that i think about it, it can be a problem with the function code, what exactly is it doing? Is there some kind of division in the function? The WHERE can be push down or up so if you have something like a > 0 AND b / a = 40 it might not work
